# App breaking when trying to use usetState in React/TypeScript app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

## Expected

Being able to use `useState` to set an email and password var inside of a functional React component.

Then using onChange on the inputs to change those variables, then sent the results of those variables up to the parent class via the `signIn` function.

## Results

There is a typescript error highlighted over the `onChange`, and the app breaks.

**Code**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

import {
  AuthArea,
  AuthInputs,
  CreateNewAccount,
  FunctionButton
} from '../../styles'

interface IProps {
  signIn(email: string, password: string): void
}

export default ({ signIn }: IProps) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  return (
    <AuthArea>
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <AuthInputs>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChange={setEmail}
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={setPassword}
        />
        <FunctionButton onClick={() => signIn(email, password)}>
          Sign In
        </FunctionButton>
        <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
      </AuthInputs>
      <CreateNewAccount>
        Create New Account
      </CreateNewAccount>
    </AuthArea>
  )
}
```

**The error**

> (JSX attribute) React.InputHTMLAttributes.onChange?: ((event: React.ChangeEvent) => void) | undefined
>   Type 'Dispatch>' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent) => void'.
>     Types of parameters 'value' and 'event' are incompatible.
>       Type 'ChangeEvent' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction'.
>         Type 'ChangeEvent' is not assignable to type '(prevState: string) => string'.
>           Type 'ChangeEvent' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: string): string'.ts(2322)
>   index.d.ts(1976, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLInputElement>'

[image]

Comment: I don't know if the syntax changes when you use typescript, but shouldn't the useState be inside the component?

Comment: @paruchuri-p ah you are right, just fixed that but still get the same error. Updating my code above...

Comment: Check the answer I posted and let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you setState in onChange:

```
<input
     type="text"
     placeholder="Email"
     value={email}
     onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
/>
<input
     type="password"
     placeholder="Password"
     value={password}
     onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version with extracted out function and using currying method for re-usability is as below:

```
export default ({ signIn }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleChange = setterFunc => e => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setterFunc(value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Email"
        value={email}
        onChange={handleChange(setEmail)}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        placeholder="Password"
        value={password}
        onChange={handleChange(setPassword)}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Here's live version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rf4bhw